# How To seperate Requests from controller for making code cleaner

Tags: php, laravel

in some cases in my controller i have to recive like 12 params from my client side and i have to like below for each of variables :

```
$something = $request->get('something');
```

this makes like 100 line of code extra in my controller for like 10 methods and i want to make my controller short and readable so i want to know if there is any way to seperate this code form my controller and recive them in my controller and use them in my method so my code will become cleaner and more readble

Comment: You can use $request->all() to get all request parameters.

Comment: I'd suggest creating Service class and migrate logic into it

Comment: Use traits or some service class for that case.

Answer (score 2):

Create Service classes to put logic in it:

```
class IngredientService
{
    /**
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function storeIngredient(array $data)
    {
        $ingredient = Ingredient::create([
            'unit_id' => array_get($data, 'unit_id'),
            'price' => array_get($data, 'price'),
            'name' => array_get($data, 'name')
        ]);

        return $ingredient;
    }
}
```

Then you use it in your controller like below:

```
class IngredientController {
  public function store(Request $request, IngredientService $ingredientService)
  {
    $ingredient = $ingredientService->store($request->toArray())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your table column and then check if the request has that column name and if so add the data to database. The first step is putting this in your model

**Model**

```
public function getTableColumns() {
    return $this->getConnection()->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($this->getTable());
}
```

And then in the controller method where you save the data:

**Controller**

```
    $something = new Something();
    $somethingColumns = $something->getTableColumns();
    foreach($somethingColumns as $column){
        if(request($column)){
            $something->$column = request($column);
        }
    }
    $something->save();
```

Comment: This is bad practice

Comment: Maybe you're right. Let's see what else can we do. You tell us.

Comment: in this way i should use all the code again but this time inside a foreach and if right ??‌so thanks to your answer but i think its not the best solution for it .

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to put the same exact name of the table's columns on your inputs in the client side. So, I think this is a bad practice too.